# シェルスクリプトから複数プロセスをバックグラウンドで実行させたい

Tags: shellscript

シェルスクリプトAで別のシェルスクリプトB,Cを違うディレクトリ上で同時に動かしたいです。シェルスクリプトB,C内には同じプログラム群を実行する内容が記述されています。

```
mkdir test1
cd test1
sh B.sh &
cd ..

mkdir test2
cd test2
sh C.sh &
cd ..
```

のようにシェルスクリプトAに記述し実行すると、シェルスクリプトB内に記述されてたプログラム群が実行されますが、それが終了するまでシェルスクリプトCの内容が動きません。

test1 と test2 上で同時に動かすことで時間を短縮することが目的なのですが、有効な方法などをご教授いただきたいです。

Comment: スクリプトを見る限り、sh B.shとsh C.shは並行しているようです、shは何をお使いですか？ls -l \`which sh\`?またOSは何を使用していますか?

Comment: bash を使っています。実行環境は以下です。ProductName:Mac OS X Server    ProductVersion:10.6.8

Comment: nekketsuuu さんのコメントとも重複しますが、なるべく実際の環境に近い情報を載せた方が具体的な回答を付けやすいと思います。ヘルプの [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) も参考にしてください。

Answer (score 1):

`sh B.sh &` と `sh C.sh &` をしているのでこれらはバックグラウンドで同時に動きます。もし C.sh の実行がブロックされているのであれば、C.sh の内容に問題がありそうです。

B.sh と C.sh では同じプログラムを実行しているとのことですが、その実行しているプログラムが同時起動を許していなかったり、他にも何かしら他方をロックする形になっていたりしませんか？

Comment: B.sh と C.sh はほとんど同じような内容になっているため C.sh の内容に問題が無いようには思えます。そのため実行しているプログラムになにかしら問題があるように思えますが、心当たりは特にありません、、

Comment: ほとんど同じ内容であるからこそ、B.sh および C.sh で同時に実行しようとしているプログラムがロックを取ろうとしているのではないかと疑っています。可能であれば質問を編集して B.sh と C.sh の中身を教えて下さい。

Comment: B.sh C.sh は 2000行ほどある複雑なシェルでした。やはりそこで実行しようとしているプログラムの方に問題があったようで、プログラム側を修正することで上手くいきました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

子プロセスを含めて、`sh A.sh`のシステムコールトレースを取れば、どこで時間がかかっているのか分かるかもしれません。
※　macの環境がないので、実際に動かしたわけではありません。

```
dtruss -e -f sh A.sh
```